# Firestore get documents with maximum value

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, google-cloud-firestore

I have a collection of documents:

```
data class Game(
    var userId: String? = "",
    var userName: String? = "",
    var date: Timestamp? = null,
    var award: Int
)
```

I want to make a rating for last week, ordered by the award and grouped by username (just 1 row for every user).

This code returns all records with repetition.

```
db.collection("games").orderBy("award", Query.Direction.DESCENDING).limit(50).get()
```

Is any way to get users with maximum award value without repetition users? Or maybe my database structure is wrong?

Answer (score 3):

Firestore doesn't offer any grouping in queries.  There are no aggregate functions as you might know from SQL type databases.

If you need to track aggregate information, you will have to find another way to record that information.  Usually that requires another collection (in your case, one document per user) where aggregate values, such as min and max values, are stored and updated as the "source" collection changes over time.

Comment: Yes, thanks. I create 2 collections: Players (userId, username, email) and Games (userId, username, date, award). User's max award value of this week will depend on the date, for ex. 01.01 - 100, 02.01 - 90, 03.01 - 80 etc. So we can't store just max value. How can I aggregate them?

Comment: You have to update the per-user aggregation document over time as the original collection changes. So, if you get a new award value, you have to check it against the document that stores the current max, and update it if there is a new max.

Comment: If I understand you mean aggregation like this https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/aggregation?hl=ru 
But it will work just for rating for all time. But, it will not work for rating for the last week. For example we have this data: 
Date -> Award: 
01/01/2020 -> 100; 
02/01/2020 -> 90; 
03/01/2020 -> 80; 
04/01/2020 -> 85. 

So, in 07/01/2020 max value is 100; 
in 08/01/2020 max value is 90;
in 09/01/2020 max value is 85.

Comment: You would need to further break down your manual aggregations by the period of time you're trying to measure. Firestore won't do any of this for you - it's up to you to model your data according to your needs.